# Question on rendering grass using billboard texture

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, shader

every one, i have been doing some work on rendering grass using billboard textures recent days, and i met some problems, 
it looks not so bad when the camera'angle with xz plane is not big, but when the angle is bigger until the camera is on the top of the billboard, it looks very bad, a cross line just can be seen, and not like real grass.

[image]

[image]

so the problems are as follow:
1. could  someone tell me how to fix this problem?(looks like cross)
2  what's more, i did not add light or other shader effect, so the result looks not real, and a more important factor is the texture i used is not good enough, could anyone provide some better texture? and teach me how to add light effect and shader effect?
Thanks a lot.
regards.

Comment: Click on the ✓ Checkmark on the left (below the number). As for your question, read [Kevin Boulanger's paper](http://www.kevinboulanger.net/grass.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use billboard grass in the distance, and real, or at least more detailed geometry up close.

Comment: There are check mark (that one → ✔) under each answer's vote buttons. Click it.